Using MacOS, what is the correct way to write a file path to another Macintosh computer connected via an SMB share?
I have 4 different computers connected to my own via SMB share and am writing a script that will access each of their hard drives & external drives and return the amount of free GB left on each. I have a script that will do this for my own computer but am struggling to understand how best to access the other computers on the network using Python.
I am not sure whether I would have to mount the drives found on each of the network computers before Python could return the amount of storage left or whether there is a particular way of writing the file path to access those on the network without having to mount them first.
If it is the latter, how would I write the file path to access each network computer? If it is the former, what is the best way to mount each of the drives and unmount them once complete?
Ideally, I would like to access each of the network computers and just run the following code:
e_hd = os.listdir("/Volumes")
no_connected = range(0, (len(e_hd)))
BytesPerGB = 1000 * 1000 * 1000

for i in no_connected:
    print(i)
    print(e_hd[i])
    path = "/Volumes/" + e_hd[i]
    total, used, free = shutil.disk_usage(path)
    print(free/BytesPerGB) 

I have tried a number of different ways of writing the file path, including using the SMB address although the path is never recognised. I have been able to access the network drives by mounting them manually in Finder although I want this process to run automatically each day, so this will not work.
Thanks in advance

Related: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/697/how-can-i-mount-an-smb-share-from-the-command-line
